# Set JAVA_HOME in JayDeBeAPI on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jdbc, windows-7, jaydebeapi

I want to connect to an Oracle database with JDBC and python. I have a Windows 7 machine. I have installed the `jaydebeapi` package.

My Windows 7 machine has the 32bit JRE installed and installing the 64bit version is not an option. The actual Windows 7 installation is 64bit.

I get an error that says that it cannot find my JAVA_HOME. How do I specify it manually?

The traceback that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 20, in <module>
  File "Z:\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py", line 381, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
  File "Z:\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py", line 175, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    jvm_path = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
  File "Z:\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py", line 337, in getDefaultJVMPath
    return finder.get_jvm_path()
  File "Z:\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jvmfinder.py", line 184, in get_jvm_path
    .format(self._libfile))
jpype._jvmfinder.JVMNotFoundException: No JVM shared library file (jvm.dll) found. Try setting up the JAVA_HOME environment variable properly.
```